# How to access from one micro service to another via zuul proxy

Tags: docker, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm developing micro services project using spring boot. Here, UI pages are in separate micro service and zuul proxy in separate micro service. I want to access UI page via zuul micro service. I have added my project structure below.

[image]

UiService Application.properties:

```
server.port=8090
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.application.name=ui
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=5
```

zuulService application.yml:

```
server:
port: 8080
eureka:
 instance:
  leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
  statusPageUrlPath: /info
  healthCheckUrlPath: /health    

logging:
 level:
  ROOT: INFO
  org.springframework.web: DEBUG
zuul:
  routes:
    ui: 
      url: http://localhost:8090
ribbon:
  eager-load:
    enabled: false
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka:
    build: eurekaService
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
  zuul:
    build: zuulService
    links:
     - eureka
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  turbine:
     build: turbineService
    links:
     - eureka
    ports:
     - "8989:8989"
  ui: 
   build: uiService
   links:
     - eureka
    ports:
     - "8090:8090"
```

uiService Structure:

[image]

My eureka service page:

[image]

After run this project in docker(docker-compose up -d), When I'm trying to access the login screen(Which is available inside uiService) getting following exception. How to solve this?

[image]

UIService Main Method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class UIApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UIApplication.class, args);
     }
    }
```

uiService pom.xml:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>uiService</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
            </dependency>

           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
           </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:8090/login` is a direct request to the UI app, no Zuul involved.

If it's not loading / displaying the page, it could be an error while starting the application or `/login` doesn't exist.

Do you mind sharing the logs?

Comment: Once i involved Zuul proxy while display login page, I got the same page as result(already attached SS). url : localhost:8080/ui/login..... i didn't get any error while deploying image into docker (docker-compose up -d).

Comment: Do you mind sharing: pom.xml, which Spring Boot version are you using and UIController that maps to GET /login?

Comment: I'm Using 1.5.2 version,

 getmapping is in uiController
  `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getLogin() {
  return "login";
 }`

above, I have added my uiService pom.xml